# 12.04 doesn't recognize my wifi Broadcom BCM94318MPG

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, broadcom

I have a Gateway MX6436 with a Broadcom BCM94318MPG WiFi. Everything else works fine but Ubuntu doesn't recognize my WiFi. It says it doesn't have the firmware.

What to do? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Install **firmware-b43-installer** from the Ubuntu Software Center.

Ubuntu already includes drivers for Broadcom hardware, but for certain reasons can't include firmware. This has to be done by the user, as shown above.